# Create folder using cmd and passing formatted date from powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, regedit

I would like to create folder where it's name is date in specific format. Date format is from powershell echo result. How could I combine this two things?

`cmd.exe /c md \"%1\%%"date%%\"" /f` and `powershell get-date -format "{yyyy-MMM-dd HHmm}`?

It must be in one line and starts with `cmd`.
I will appreciate for any help.

Comment: deadfish, I created a context menu solution, as you requested before completely overhauling your question. Because you've visited since my answer without comment, I have now checked and can confirm that it works on both Windows 10 _(v1709)_ and Windows 7 platforms.

Comment: Deadfish, So the "one-liner" requirement wasn't real?  I see you removed it. Why exactly do you insist on running a powershell command from cmd.exe?  Using it in a batch script? You don't need powershell to accomplish your task if that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you are looking in powershell:

```
$format=get-date -format "yyyy-MMM-dd HHmm"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\Folder\$format"
```

This is the one liner from the cmd prompt:

```
Powershell -command "New-Item -Name (get-date -format 'yyyy-MMM-dd HHmm') -ItemType Directory -Path 'C:\Folder' -Force"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but i need use `cmd` and it must be in one line

Comment: @deadfish: I have given the one liner that you can directly run from the cmd prompt

Comment: Well I needed to run it with `cmd` however it succeed by using `cmd /c` + your inline. Thanks.

Comment: @deadfish, that's pointless, just run powershell directly. Anywhere you can launch `cmd.exe` you can and SHOULD run `powershell.exe`.

Comment: @jwdonahue: How are you justifying that it is pointless. May be he is doing integration from other app. one liner is important in multiple orchestrators even.

Comment: This one liner was for regedit command. Raw powershell didn't work for me.

Comment: @RanadipDutta, you can run a powershell script directly in a one liner, no need for the cmd.exe invocation. The gain you might get from cmd.exe is the ease of redirecting output, but I see no evidence that is required, and there are simple pure Powershell workarounds for that as well.

Comment: @deadfish, a powershell script can do everything stated in your problem statement without cmd.exe, including registry manipulations.  Powershell is a first-class scripting environment in Windows. If all you want is a one liner that can be invoked anywhere, why add the extra cmd.exe process?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it in a single line in the cmd, try this. This will still just powershell to run. But you can run it from a bat file,
`powershell $date = get-date -format "{yyyy-MMM-dd HHmm}; md c:\temp\$date`

Else you can run it in powershell

```
    $date = get-date -format "{yyyy-MMM-dd HHmm}"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "c:\temp\$date"
```

Hope this helps.

/Anders

Answer (score 0):

If you're still wanting a right-click context menu entry, *(which creates a directory named using the format you've provided)*, you can do so by just entering this single line into a Command prompt window.

```
Powershell -NoP -C "New-Item 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\MkStampedDir' -Value 'NOW Folder Here' -Force"; "New-Item 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\MkStampedDir\command' -Value '\"C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe\" -NoP -C \"$dt = get-date -f {yyyy-MMM-dd HHmm}; MD \"\"%V\"\"\$dt\"\"\"' -Force"
```

This should create a context menu entry named `NOW Folder Here`, seen when you right click in an empty area of an explorer window, *(and  probably the desktop)*. When the entry is selected a powershell command should run creating the directory in that folder.