# How I do invoke a PowerShell Start-Process command with arguments that require quoting from a Command Prompt / batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, syntax, quoting

I am getting this error when trying exec one command in `PowerShell`:

[image]

I am trying to `exec` this command:

```
powershell.exe Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\attrib +h +s "%CD%"" -Verb runAs
```

Can someone please help me figuring out why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Your question title is asking how to execute a command in PowerShell, but you appear to be executing a file designed for cmd.exe with cmd.exe arguments via PowerShell in cmd.exe! **Why?**

Comment: If this question is related to your [lastest one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50901368/6738015) then it's pointless, because you can run a `PowerShell Start-Process ...` command directly from the right-click context menu registry location, _you don't need cmd.exe to be involved at all!_

Comment: Also in PowerShell, you can set the current directory attributes without `attrib.exe` too! `$(Get-Item $(Get-Location)).Attributes='Hidden,System'`.

Comment: @Compo: True, `cmd.exe` is not implicitly involved when you invoke File Explorer context-menu commands defined via the registry. Since you therefore do not have access to environment variables, `%CD%` must be replaced with `%V`, which is a placeholder for the full path to the right-clicked folder. With respect to quoting, however, essentially the same rules apply as when calling from `cmd.exe`, and it is the quoting that is the OP's main problem.

Comment: @mklement0, I'm aware of the process in [creating a context menu entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49115386/6738015), but this question is still about the 'current directory'. The OP hasn't yet confirmed that the two questions are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone please help me figure out why this is happening?

The `-FilePath` parameter of the `Start-Process` cmdlet expects the name or path of an executable *file* by itself, not an *entire command line*.

The *arguments* to pass to the executable specified via `-FilePath` must be passed *separately*, as an *array*, via the `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter.

When calling from `cmd.exe` (a batch file), it's conceptually cleaner to pass the entire command line to be evaluated by *PowerShell* in a single, `"`-enclosed argument:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath attrib.exe -Args +h, +s, '\"%CD%\"'"
```

Note the need to escape the `%CD%` value *doubly*, by enclosing it in `'` for the sake of PowerShell first, then in `\"`  inside that: The outer `'` ensures that PowerShell itself recognizes the value as a single argument, and the embedded `\"` quoting ensures that the ultimate target program, `attrib.exe`, sees the value as a single argument too.

This need for double escaping is unfortunate and shouldn't be necessary - it is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576).

Answer (score 0):

The is no need to fully qualify the path to attrib.exe, it's natively available via the DOS and PoSH environment variables.

```
powershell attrib 'd:\temp\SomeFile.txt'
# A                    D:\temp\SomeFile.txt

powershell attrib +r 'd:\temp\SomeFile.txt'

powershell attrib 'd:\temp\SomeFile.txt'
# A    R               D:\temp\SomeFile.txt
```

Any strings with spaces must be enclosed in quotes, as well as arguments or they must be passed separately.

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command  &{ $ConsoleCommand }" -Wait
```

All you are doing, in your use case and what I show, is calling PoSH to run a DOS command that you can just do in DOS. So, why use PoSH at all for this, other than the runas thing?

Also, as you do command they way you are trying, proper quoting to properly qualify that command to run can be confusing. Which is the real issue with that line.
Passing arguments have to be done properly, spaces if not properly handled will cause issues, hence your error.

Also, why start at cmd.exe for this effort, just to end up shelling out to the PoSH console host to run this command?

Just do this natively in PoSH console host, which by nature is what you are doing. Save yourself the extra steps and complications.

Just launch powershellexe, instead of cmd.exe and run your DOS commands.

```
attrib +r 'd:\temp\SomeFile.txt'
```

There is little cmd.exe can do that PoSH console cannot and there are tons of things PoSH (console host and ISE) can do that cmd.exe cannot. 
So, why not just start and stay in PoSH natively?

You can run all you DOS commands in PoSH console host (in the ISE, there is a little bit more effort to get them to work) natively, or just use the PoSH equivalent.

> Use a PowerShell Cmdlet to Work with File Attributes ---
>   'blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/26/use-a-powershell-cmdlet-to-work-with-file-attributes'

That one is a bit long in the tooth, I know. However, you can just do following as well, to get the attributes, and modifying them using similar but a different cmdlet.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp\SomeFile.txt').Attributes
# ReadOnly, Archive

# or this
(gci 'D:\Temp\SomeFile.txt').Attributes

# or this
(dir 'D:\Temp\SomeFile.txt').Attributes

# or this
(ls 'D:\Temp\SomeFile.txt').Attributes
```

Each of the above do exactly the same thing.
Setting attributes is just this...

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'D:\Temp\SomeFile.txt'-Name IsReadOnly -Value $false

# or
sp 'D:\Temp\SomeFile.txt' IsReadOnly $false

(ls 'D:\Temp\SomeFile.txt').Attributes
# Archive
```

Sure you can use .bat to call a PoSH script file. But if you are just sitting at a terminal, pick one or the other based on what is needed.

Comment: The OP is trying to run `attrib.exe` _elevated_ via `Start-Process -Verb RunAs`, something that _direct_ invocation cannot do - whether in `cmd.exe` or in PowerShell.
The OP's specific problem is the attempt to pass the entire `attrib` _command line_ to `Start-Process -FilePath`, whereas `-FilePath` only expects the target _executable_ (file name / path), with
its arguments needing to be passed separately via `-ArgumentList`.

Comment: A few asides: Please don't refer to [`cmd.exe` ("Command Prompt")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) as "DOS" - the latter only applies to the obsolete MS-DOS and Windows 9x operating systems.
Similarly, while "PoSH" (and case varations thereof) has some history behind it, I suggest staying away from it for the sake of clarity - the official name, "PowerShell",  is only slightly longer.
Please use full URLs when quoting external resources, so that they appear as directly clickable links in the answer.